# How to convert .pck ( Python Pickle object ) files into .jpeg format

Tags: python, dataset, data-science

I have a dataset of knee bone MRI but it is in .pck format can anyone help me regarding converting it into the .jpeg format or .png

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code. Moreover a pickle file can contain nearly any type of object. First you must find out which type it is, e. g. unpickle and use "type".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what Python library was used to create or load the images that were saved as .pcks, yes.

You first need to load the pickle files as objects again using the `pickle.load()` method ([documentation here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle)) and then save them again using whatever library was used to make them in the first place. In the case of OpenCV, you would use the `cv2.imwrite()` method, for PIL it's `Image.save()`. If you aren't using those, just look up the documentation for whatever library you're using on saving images.

If you don't know what library was used to make the images, you'll have to see what the data you get after loading the file looks like before you can do anything else.